# Set default font family for entire project

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building portfolio using **html, css, core php, javascript, vuejs, mysql.**
I want to set **monospace** font family as **default** frontend font family.
I am not using any **php** framework, is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: Set a CSS rule? Include that stylesheet everywhere?

Comment: If you aren't using PHP, then don't tag your question with PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Scott Marcus. I am using mysql database and for connecting database i am using php too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set default font in body - and everything will be set with this default CSS font.
Later if you crate DIV's you can change this font.

Example style.css

```
body {
       font-family: monospace, Times, serif;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the previous answer, you can do it with *CSS*, include the css file in a boilerplate make and all your html files use that boilerplate  which is the best practice.

file.css:

```css
body {
       font-family: monospace, Times, serif;
     }
```

Then in the html file inside **head** tag

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href=":pathToCssFile">
```

Where :pathToCssFile is (most of the time) the relative path to the css file for example: `./css/file.css`
But if you want to do it by clicking a button, you can do:
(In a js file that you attach to your html)

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btnClass");
btn.addEventListener("click", e =>{
       document.body.style.fontFamily = "monospace, Times, serif"
});
```

Or in js as soon as the page loads, add this in the html (I suggest you to use the css approach)

```html
<script>
    document.body.style.fontFamily = "monospace, Times, serif"
</script>
```